# How can I add css to Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using Lightbox and I want to change its default style..
I use `makeStyles`.

```js
<Lightbox
  images={[{src:imageRef.current}]}
  isOpen={imgDialogOpen}
  onClose={closeImgDialog}
/>
```

It has a default class called `content_1h4z6hc` and I want to add a few more things to it like `background-color`.

How should I do this?

Comment: What's the package of `Lightbox` name?

Comment: react-images-zoom-print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-images-zoom-print` doesn't support pass props to update css. So you can use your css to ovreride the default css.

This package using id `lightboxBackdrop`. So you can base on that to write your css:

```
#lightboxBackdrop {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-hopper-q94z7?file=/src/styles.css:59-109

Comment: I updated my questions according to your answer.How do I do this using makeStyles?

Comment: makeStyles only use for material-ui

Comment: add css file and import to component like code example

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `activeProps`, try please like this:

```
activeProps={{width: '10px'}}
```

or directly you can use styles

```
<Lightbox
    style={{ width: 10 }}
    backgroundColor="#000"
  >
    <Image
      style={{
        borderRadius: 15,
        width: "100%", 
      }}
      resizeMethod="resize"
      resizeMode="cover"
    />
  </Lightbox>
```

Comment: This is what you mean?  ` <Lightbox
        images={[{src:imageRef.current}]}    activeProps={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>`